# Не могу получить кадр из видео

Tags: gd, ffmpeg, php

Не получаю кадр из видео. Ошибок в коде не замечаю.

```
class Movie {

    public function screen($file) {

        $movie = new ffmpeg_movie($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/'.$file);

        $frame = 10;

        $image = $movie->getFrame($frame);
        $show_img = $image->toGDImage();

        header("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng($show_img);
        imagedestroy($show_img);

    }

}
```

Поддержка ffmpeg и GD есть. В чем тут загвоздка?

Comment: Выводит-то что? В файл сохраняет? А нужо ли вообще `$des_img`?

Comment: @Etki выводит http://xdup.ru/files/8182_1.png в файл не сохраняет

Comment: @rnddev я имел в виду если в файл срендерить, то что будет?

Comment: @Etki проблема в header("Content-type: image/png");

Чем его заменить не знаю, так как при выводе с html кодом, выводит так как на скрине, есль просто

 $mov = new Movie;
 echo $mov->screen('1404992261.mp4');

то всё работает

Comment: Что за бред, *** все сохранено в UTF8 без BOM, пробелов нигде лишних нету. Какого черта не выводи изображение

Comment: @rnddev отрубить генерацию картинки (закомментировать строчку вывода), сделать content-type: text/plain, посмотреть в консоли хрома, какой response приходит